# Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, iphone-sdk-4.1

I developed an app for iPhone with Xcode 3.2.4 and iOS 4.1. Now I want to test my app on my iPhone, but I don't want to enroll for a developer program. I searched in google and found a lot of tutorials, but they are not working.
Then I asked me if it is because I use iOS 4.1. Is there a way to test the app?
I've a jailbroken iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1.

Comment: $99 is a pretty reasonable price to pay for excellent developer tools, IMHO.

Comment: $99 certainly is reasonable. The tools however, are terrible. I always figured it was because access to the tools were only $99. :-)

Comment: $99 is the starting fee. After the purchase, they'll consider if they need more legal proof, like a notary signed document, which can be much more expensive. All this to test an app on your own device ? I dont think thats reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to install SSH to your device to be able to copy files via scp.

Build your application and grab the binary from your build directory. Copy it to the device's /Applications folder using `scp`. Change the permissions to 755 recursively using `chmod -R 755 ApplicationName.app`, reboot your iPhone.

And I strongly encourage you to enroll in the Developer Program and pay Apple for the work they have done in creating this great SDK.

Comment: Yes. I did that before but when I want to start the app the crashes and returns to the springboard.

I will do that, but before I want to test my application on a real device and not in the simulator.
But thank you!!

Comment: Maybe it is your application that causes the crash. Did you try compiling and installing an open source application like iProxy?

Comment: Okay. Thank you! How can I compile an open source application?

Comment: Just like you compiled your own application. Open the .xcodeproj file in Xcode and hit Build (Cmd+B).

Comment: If an app works on the simulator, it should work on the device. You do not develop for the simulator, you just use it to test your app. But no, there is no difference in coding for either "platform"

Comment: Now I created a navigation controller based project with Core Data and on the device it closes the application. So I think the problem is Core Data which I use in my project, too.

Comment: I got it with this tutorial: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398 ! Thank you muffix