# Is there any way to test iphone application on real device without paying $99 to Apple?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to test iphone application on real device without paying $99 to Apple because i dnt want to enrolled to apple iphone developer program i m newbie just playing around with iphone development.

Comment: Why does it have to be on a real device? You can use Xcode to build an app and use the simulator for free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy an iPhone Application from Xcode to real iPhone device without having an Apple 99$ Certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151705/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device-without-h)

Comment: @rwilliams: Yes. Testing on real devices is not restricted to enterprise developers.

Comment: Thanks grillz but i have iphone 3gs thats why i want to try on it.

Comment: Two downvotes... and then two upvotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append your app into jailbroken device using cross-compiller and iphone toolchain. But there are some complexity with doing this. And you will no be able to debug it anyway without subscribing apple dev program. So, it's easier to subscribe.

If you still want to, goto http://www.saurik.com/