# IPhone device test

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to test iphone application on real device without paying $99 to Apple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151828/is-there-any-way-to-test-iphone-application-on-real-device-without-paying-99-to)

I'm creating some app's for IPhone and I'm registered as Apple developer but I can't tested on my iPhone just on Xcode simulators. I didn't pay the 99$ to develop for IOS, do I need to pay it to be able to test on my device?

Thank you!

Comment: yes you need to register to Apple Developer account, after that only you can create provisioning profile with that UDID attached

Comment: It think this belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legally yes. There's also the jailbreak way. If you jailbreak your device you can run applications signed with a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

YES
You need to register to [Apple Developer account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/), after that only you can create provisioning profile with your device UDID attached

But as you are developing apps, you are going to deploy on App Store for which Developer Account is mandatory. So its, better you go for Developer Account now it-self

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pay out. Anyway, later you will want to submit your app. Submitting will work only with paid account membership fee.