# How to run my application on my jailBreaked iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have a jailbreaked iPhone....
is there any way to run my application on my device without intracting with apple website....i mean

- without adhoc....
- getting that certificate from any other website for free....

i am really not aware of jailbreaked iPhones......What should i do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple/)

---

First, you need to install SSH to your device to be able to copy files via scp.

Build your application and grab the binary from your build directory. Copy it to the device's /Applications folder using scp. Change the permissions to 755 recursively using chmod -R 755 ApplicationName.app, reboot your iPhone.

And I strongly encourage you to enroll in the Developer Program and pay Apple for the work they have done in creating this great SDK.