# How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sdk

How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to real iPhone device without having a US$99 Apple certificate?

UPDATE: I don't khow how to deploy. YES I Have Jailbreaked Iphone.

Comment: Do you mean a non jail broken phone (which afaik can't be done) or a jailbroken phone?

Comment: That method, if available, changes a lot depending on your Xcode. Did you try googling it?

Comment: You can try jailbreaking your device, check this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

Comment: To your question - you can't without a developer account.

Comment: See also [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple)

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to jailbreak your phone, and even there I'm not sure whether you can deploy directly from Xcode.

The problem is a "normal" iPhone requires a signed binary and the only official way to sign an app is by using a certificate "blessed" by Apple.

Comment: I have jailbreaked Iphone. By I don't khow how to deploy.