# iOS development without developer account (no AppStore)

Tags: ios

Is there a way to try our iOS application on an iDevice without a paid developer account (legally), or we can only try it with the emulator ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you jailbreak your device, you can easily test your application directly on your device (and even write it on your device if you wish). Just go to http://jailbrea.kr/ to figure out what to use to jailbreak your device. Then, you have to set up xcode to compile without codesigning. After you do this, use a program called "ldid" to sign your binary: `ldid -S myAppsExecutable`. Then, just SSH the .app folder over to your device in /Applications, restart springboard (`killall SpringBoard` on the device), and click the icon.

Comment: see the question ... (legally) HAve you read the question ?

Comment: Jailbreaking is completely legal. It was passed by the DMCA over 2 years ago.

Comment: Yes is so legal that Apple itself encourage it :- ) Are you serious ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#United_States_legal_status

Comment: In US maybe ... I don't know in Europe NO for sure.

Comment: Jailbreaking IS legal. No need to downvote this answer.

Comment: I have not downvoted the question but Jailbreak is not legal in Europe and it is unsupported by Apple ...

Comment: Learn to use google before asking a dumb question. Don't downvote something if you have no idea what your'e talking about: http://www.computerweekly.com/news/1280093396/Apple-iPhone-jailbreaking-is-okay-under-EU-law

Comment: Again ... I have NOT downvoted your question !

Comment: That wasn't directed solely to you, only the first sentence. The other sentence was to whoever else downvoted this correct answer.

Comment: Do you want to teach me how to use Google ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that's interesting !

Comment: aleroot: Actually, I wasn't addressing you with that sentence, got you and someone else mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "legally" as "without jailbreaking" (which is wrong, since jailbreaking is legal), then no, it's not possible.

If you mean "legally" in its correct sense (i. e. without conflicting with laws), then yes, it's possible: jailbreak your device, and simply insall your application. You still may need to fake codesign it for the iOS kernel to run it.